# How to make python functools.lru_cache returned value immutable?

Tags: python-3.x, caching, functools, lru

In my python3.9 project, I use functools.lru_cache to speed up some of my functions’ performance.

But in some calls, I modified the result of the cached functions, which may lead to errors, since for the next call, the result could be wrong.

How could I make the result immutable, which make my program fail fast? Then I could find out the wrong modification and fix it.

Comment: That depends on the exact type of those objects. Why don't you provide a small example? The simplest would be to always work with a shallow or deep copy of whatever the function returns

Comment: I use cache decorator on lots of functions in my project, returns single object instance, dict and list of int/string/object instance.